# How to remove subpath from PATH variable using python

Tags: python

I have added path to $PATH variable using below command:

```
import os

os.environ["ORACLE_HOME"] = </linux path>
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + os.pathsep.join([X + "/OPatch"])
```

Once I am done with my activity, I want to remove added path to $PATH variable. Can you give me an example how it can be done using Python

Comment: It might be easier to only add it to the environment of your subprocess, for example, `subprocess.run([...], env={**os.environ, os.environ['PATH'] + os.pathsep + os.path.join(X, "OPatch")})` or to skip modifying `PATH` entirely: `subprocess.run([os.path.join(X, "OPatch", prog), ...])`.

Comment: Why not just `saved = os.environ["PATH"]`, do your stuff here, then `os.environ["PATH"] = saved`

Comment: You do not need to change it if you want to change it before script ends. When you set a variable like that `os.environ["PATH"]`, it will only available for this script and it's subprocesses. After script ends it will be gone.

Comment: Thanks Justin...your suggestion works